# When does $A-A$ avoid $A$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, probability-distributions, additive-combinatorics

[Chavez and Allawala](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.02280) recently used a statistical model to explain the empirical observation that the imaginary parts of the nontrivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function form a set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}_+$ with the property that the difference set $A-A$ "avoids" $A$:

[image]

I'd like to understand an extreme version of this behavior. Given a discrete $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}_+$ and $s,t>0$, let $p_{A,s,t}$ denote the probability distribution of $Y-X$, where $(X,Y)$ is drawn uniformly from the set

$$\{(a_1,a_2)\in A\times A:a_2-a_1<s,~a_1<a_2<t\}.$$

I am interested in $A$ such that for every fixed $s>0$, the weak limit of $p_{A,s,t}$ as $t\to\infty$ is a continuous distribution with a continuous density function that vanishes at $A$.

> **Question:** What are necessary and sufficient conditions for such a set?

This seems like a distributional version of various ideas that I've seen in additive combinatorics, but I don't know if there's a deeper connection beyond analogy.

Comment: Density is only defined up to null sets, of which the discrete set $A$ is an example, so this notion might not be well defined.  (In the specific case of Riemann zeroes, by the way, the density is expected to converge to uniform in the limit, as the amplitude of these dips is predicted to be asymptotically smaller than the mean density.)

Comment: @TerryTao Thanks! Indeed, I want a continuous pdf in the limit, and the Riemann zeros are just motivation the extreme behavior discussed in my question. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: 1. It's conjectured that the Riemann zeros are linearly independent. 2. $A-A$ avoids $A$ is the same as $A+A$ avoids $A$, right?